# Same intent filter for multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

I have a multiple activities that should use the same intent filter, defined in the manifest file like following:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/mainTitle" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.example.Activity1">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.example.Activity2">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.example.Activity3">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So when the user would like to share image to my application, it will be shown 3 times.

How to handle it using only one intent filter? (so also only one would be shown for user when sharing)

I am not able to define some kind of rule through which I can decide which activity should be used as all of these activities are performing different actions and user is just choosing "open in my app".

Comment: Found an answer yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can have one activity, that declares that intent filters, and later decide what particular activity to launch within that activity in runtime.